# Dynamically adding the popover (ngx bootstrap) through nativeElemet

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have a directive in angular 6, through which I am getting the nativeElement of the control. How to add the ngx-popover in my directive to that element?

something like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
        popover="this is my text">
  Live demo
</button>
```

In above example I want to first find the button with class or id (which i will get through nativeElement) and then add "popover = 'this is my text'" to the html control.

Comment: Angular doesn't work that way. If you want to add directives to DOM elements you use the HTML templates.

Comment: @cgTag Can you please provide a small example, similar to what i wanted to achieve

Comment: Can anyone put a update on it, please

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The Popover showing up when the button has been pressed?